# How can I launch a command, wait 2 seconds and return the output without killing the command?

Tags: bash, php

I'm trying to launch a command from php with shell_exec which calls a bash script that launches a program that stays running, but sometimes this program throws an error and exit, what I need is a way of calling the script and after 2 seconds return whatever the program outputed, if the program launched correctly I just want it to return the PID and that it stays running on Linux but PHP continues, if it throws an error and closes I want the output of that error, here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

ezstream -c $1 &
ezpid=$!
echo $ezpid
sleep 2
disown
```

If it throws an error it returns well with the error message, but if it runs normally PHP gets stuck and never returns because the program keeps running, how can I make the script return even if it kept running after 2 seconds?

How can I do it with bash?, I was able to do this in C# with the Process class like this

```
    Process ez = new Process();
    //ez.parameters
    ez.Start();

    if (ez.WaitForExit(2000))
    {
        string message = ez.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        return message;
    }

    return ez.Id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
#!/bin/bash

ezstream -c $1 >log.txt 2>error.txt & 
ezpid=$!
echo $ezpid
sleep 2
if ps | grep $ezpid ; then
    echo ezsteam is still running!
    cat log.txt
    exit 0
else
    echo ezstream is dead
    cat error.txt
    exit 1
fi
```